# Unable To Publish MAUI App for Mac OS from Windows

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core, maui

I have Visual Studio Community (Version 17.4.3) in my PC.

- I created a **MAUI app and now need to publish it as a 'pkg' or 'app'
  to a Mac device from Windows**.
- I have MacOS 12 running in VMWare Workstation to test the app.
- I've not installed Visual Studio For Mac in VMWare because I'm not planning to develop in Mac.
- My intension is to develop and build on Windows as self-contained & then transfer pkg file to Mac for just running and testing

The issue is I was unable to publish for Mac from Windows.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my simple app (It's just a test app)
[image]

This is the command I'm using to try publishing for Mac but it gives me errors.

`dotnet publish -f net7.0-maccatalyst -r osx-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true`

[image]

When I try to list all workloads installed, This is what I can see
[image]

But when I checked Individual Components in Visual Studio Installer, I'm assuming SDKs are installed
[image]

This is my csproj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MacTest</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MacTest</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.mactest</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>13c5b601-4ac2-49be-a1e0-86c80ce0f8b0</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <GenerateAppInstallerFile>False</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
        <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
        <AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>False</AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>
        <GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
        <HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: the valid runtime identifier would be `maccatalyst-x64` instead of `osx-x64`. But even with the right arguments and no error publish the output is not usable. You have to use macOS for builing app or pkg

Comment: You do not have to install VS on macOS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/macos/cli?source=recommendations&view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @SirRufo - When you say 'output is not usable' what do you mean? If you mean I can't run it on Windows, Yes I don't need to. I just need to publish on Windows and transfer it to a Mac on my VMWare for running it. Will that work?

Comment: @SirRufo, The URL guide refers how can I use dotnet CLI on Mac. But I want to use in Windows. Mac I only need to run the final app

Comment: I would like to know 'From a Windows machine can I build a pkg for Mac'. If yes 'What is the command'

Comment: You can run the dotnet client on windows and build for maccatalyst, but ... the output is not usable **on the mac**. And reading carefully the link I gave you gives you a hint: You need Xcoode. Xcode is only running on macOS. There is no such thing as building for iOS (which also needs Xcode) where you have to pair a mac. Conclusion: It is **not possible** to build a MAUI app for macOS on windows platform. Period.

Comment: The only option is to install the CLI version - read the link - and build the app on macOS. Installation of VS is not required.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be a clear answer now - 'Not possible from Windows', That's it! I installed maui workload in Mac but I can't install XCode, It says I need to update OS from 12 to 14. But now I feel my purpose itself is in vein. I though I can build and test in a least supported Mac. To make sure my app has no compatability issues in Mac. But if I update the Mac Machine to latest I don't know what to do now. Any suggessions @SirRufo?

Comment: Sorry, but there is at this time no macOS 14. The latest macOS version is 13.2.1. The latest Xcode version is 14.2. I have macOS 12.6.3 running with latest Xcode 14.2 and no problem with MAUI publishing.

Comment: Latest XCode needs minimum 12.5. Mine is 12

Comment: Sorry for saying 14. I'm mostly a Windows guy. I use Mac on VMWare only to just test if my apps works there. I don't prefer coding on Mac, Windows looks the best for development is what I personally felt

Comment: It is not possible to publish macos applications in windows, you need to perform operations on mac. You can't update your XCode now, right? Is your problem solved now?

Comment: I can't update XCode because it needs Mac OS 12.5 and I have 12. I'm thinking of using an older XCode. Updating OS makes my effort in vein as I want to test run builded MAUI app in 12.0 only

Comment: You can try to use the old version of XCode and VS to see if it can be released normally. In addition, I see that you are using VMWare, and I suggest you use a real Mac to operate.

Answer (score 2):

.NET MAUI apps that target Mac Catalyst can only be launched and debugged using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. Please see [Build your first app.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=devices-maccatalyst&view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin#:%7E:text=.NET%20MAUI%20apps%20that%20target%20Mac%20Catalyst%20can%20only%20be%20launched%20and%20debugged%20using%20Visual%20Studio%202022%20for%20Mac.) In addition, archiving and publishing a .NET MAUI macOS should be through the command-line, remote building/archiving/publishing from Windows are nor supported, please see: [Publish a .NET MAUI app for macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/macos/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0) and
[.NET MAUI macOS target publishing/archiving. #5399](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5399)